# Are there good reasons for the prefixes and suffixes in the table of correlatives?

Tags: history, correlatives

Zamenhof's innovation of the table of correlatives (AFAIK the first one in any language) is brilliant, but I was always a little perplexed by some of the oddities in it. So I am wondering if anyone know the reasoning behind some of the choices.

1. The proximity marker *ĉi* distinguishes between "this" and "that." Since the distinction is only used with demonstratives, it appears that Esperanto has one demonstrative prefix and one modifier instead of two prefixes. That saves nothing and makes for awkward expressions like "*tio kaj ĉi tio.*"
2. Since we are at *ĉi*, why is the universality marker *ĉi-*? I would think more obvious choices would be "omni-" or "tuti-". At the same time, since the question marker is *ĉu*, it would be easier to remember *ĉi-* as the question prefix.
3. Why on earth is the location marker *-e*? That's the ending for adverbs and would probably make more sense for what is now *-el*, modality.
4. Speaking of which, *-el* and *-om* are for qualities and quantities respectively, except that *-el* can also be used for quantities of uncountable things. *Except* being a word that Esperanto doesn't like in its grammar.
5. Also, there is nothing about the language that says that *-el* is related to quality, while *-al* to cause. It's just something one has to learn without any helpful connection to quality or cause.

These are just examples that illustrate why the correlatives give me pause, not criticism of the language or attempts to reform it. The question is, **why** did Zamenhof pick these prefixes and suffixes, and whether there has been historically any criticism of the choices.

Comment: Regarding 1: I have seen *ĉi* used with the universal correlatives such as *ĉi ĉio*, which would mean ‘all this’ or something similar.

Comment: Regarding 5, there's also nothing about the language which says that "bona" means "good" rather than "bad": it's just something one has to learn. The basic roots are arbitrary in any language.

Comment: Yes, and I was not referring to the fact itself they are arbitrary, but that they are so similar *and* arbitrary. It's like the difference between *trinki* and *drinki*: both mean almost the same thing and are spelled almost the same. Took me years to remember which one is which.

Answer (score 6):

I think this was clearly a case of Zamenhof using a system that was in common use among Romance languages.

For example the proximal pronouns in French are (ce, ici, ci) and in Italian it's (ci)

So, it appears that he took both the idea and form from those languages.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 3: Locations are expressed with adverbials, so the adverb ending makes sense here.

To say ‘at home’ in German, you can either use the prepositional phrase *zu Hause* or the adverb *zuhause*. It is even easier to see this in Scandinavian languages. For example, ‘home’ in Norwegian is *hjem*, and ‘at home’ is *hjemme* – it's clearly an adverb, without any trace of a preposition. That wouldn't be the only thing in Esperanto that comes from Scandinavian languages, another one is the word *ju*.

Answer (score 0):

Esperanto isn't perfect and it will never be. All languages have some oddities.

> That saves nothing and makes for awkward expressions like "tio kaj ĉi
>   tio."

We used to say the exact same thing in English - "This here book." It doesn't sound awkward to me.

> At the same time, since the question marker is ĉu, it would be easier
>   to remember ĉi- as the question prefix.

I don't think people have a hard time remembering it. If the word was **Omni** then it would sound like a lot like **Oni**.

> Why on earth is the location marker -e?

Do you mean like **hejme** (at home)? **Hejme** actually means **homely**.

> Speaking of which, -el and -om are for qualities and quantities
>   respectively, except that -el can also be used for quantities of
>   uncountable things. Except being a word that Esperanto doesn't like in
>   its grammar.

I don't understand this comment. Could you clarify please?

> The question is, why did Zamenhof pick these prefixes and suffixes,
>   and whether there has been historically any criticism of the choices.

There has always been a lot of criticism. Because it a constructed language, many people feel that they can change it the way you change an open source coding project. I know a professor of linguistics and he always tells his students that languages are arbitrary. Don't expect them to make sense, even if they are constructed.

Comment: I second the question about -e: I believe that what was meant was the ending of kie, tie, etc. Why not reserve those for adverbs instead and choose something else for places? Ki**a**? Rapid**a**. Ki**e**? Rapid**e**